# Segmentation fault when using some OpenCV functions

Tags: python, c++, linux, opencv, segmentation-fault

This question might seem vague, but to be frank, that's all I've got and I'm unable to debug this issue as well.

I'm using Linux Mint and was using OpenCV for a long time now. Everything was working fine, until a few weeks back. Now, when I try to do some basic transformations, like transpose, or cvtColor, a segmentation fault pops up. I have really no idea when or how this started happening. Here is the minimal python script which returns me the error:

```
import cv2
im1 = cv2.imread("test.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
im2 = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR)
```

I did the same in C++ as well, just in case:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>                                          
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>                                          

int main() {                                                                    
    cv::Mat im1, im2;                                                           
    im1 = cv::imread("test.png", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);                                               
    cv::cvtColor(im1, im2, cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGR);                                 
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Please note that I'm using COLOR_RGBA2BGR because the test.png file under consideration do have the alpha channel.

The same segmentation fault happens when I tried transpose() as well. This was in a different program I had written sometime back. The same program works flawlessly in another machine. I had always assumed this error could be something related to mismatches in image size or something, but unfortunately, its not.

I'm not sure what other functions returns this error. I have uninstalled OpenCV, built from source, installed again and still the error persists. The only option I feel is left for me is to fresh install the OS, but any form of help to debug this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try using gdb to see where the segfault comes from?

Comment: I just did now and it seems the problem is related to OpenCL. Backtrace showed up lot of libOpenCL stuff. I remember playing around with it sometime back, but its weird since I haven't mentioned OpenCL while compiling OpenCV. So I guess I just have to get rid of OpenCL and try again.

Comment: ok, I'll add this as an aswer so people know you're on the good track :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help! Upvoted the answer, but I'm low on reputations now.

Comment: you don't need any reputation to accept an answer... (and you will even get 2 reputation points when you do that).

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about the "accepting" part. I just did. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not related to your OS, python nor C++. I recommend using `gdb` to trace back where the segfault occurs; that should point you in the right direction.